# res.redirect not working when using no template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I was making a project using express generator with the --no-view flag, and when I tried to redirect the response to a website (for example :  [www.google.com](http://www.google.com))  it didn't work (code below) :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.redirect('https://www.google.com')
});
```

The above code actually rendered the index.html (default) so I tried to reproduce the same issue this time using a template engine like pug, but this time the redirect worked.

My question is why when using no template engine the / route always renders index.html no matter what code I put inside ?

Comment: My guess is some middleware further up the script is catching the `/` route.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG for your response, actually it is quite wierd since I only made changes to this one line ``` res.redirect('https://www.google.com') ``` after creating the project, so this is default behaviour, that when using the --no-view flag the / route doesn't respond to any changes in code and only renders this index.html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index.html` file is served by following line because the project is created without view (and due to this, `app.js` wouldn't have code related to setting-up the view engine).

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

As per [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), by default `index` file of the specified directly is going to be served. You can disable it by making `index` to `false` as follow.

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), { index: false }));
```